# Working with Lift XHTML/HTML in Netbeans

Tags: html, scala, netbeans, xhtml, lift

I am developing a Lift application using Netbeans and I have everything working apart from the lift xhtml, which is stored with an html extension, creates a number of warning and errors in netbeans for example:

```
<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
      <div class="lift:HomePage">
            <h2>Summary</h2>
      </div>
</lift:surround>
```

Gives me the errors

```
> Element "lift:surround" not allowed as child of element "body" in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
Content model for element 'body':
Flow content.
From line 1, column 1; to line 1, column 43
(Rule Category: Elements structure)

Element name "lift:surround" cannot be represented as XML 1.0.
From line 1, column 1; to line 1, column 43
(Rule Category: All Other)
----
```

Is there a way to configure Netbeans so it does not present these errors when this is valid Lift coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you can rewrite all the `lift:xxx` tags differently to make parsers that expect HTML happy — for instance, with `<lift:surround>`:

```
<div class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
  ... as before ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it doesn't directly solve the issue I am having, which I think is more of a Netbeans configuration than a Lift issue, but it is useful to know.

Comment: @AlexC Right. But if you use this style, then NetBeans won't complain any more, because a `<div>` is perfectly allowed inside `<body>`.

Comment: True and that works for the trivial example that I have produced to replicate the issue but with a much larger base of code, which I already have, this is not such a neat option, and also doesn't seem to be idiomatic Lift.

Comment: Using something like <div class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content"> is actually the prefer way these days (mixed with using html5 templates. There is a lot of documentation out there using the "old" style though. Even more, David just added support for a better html5 snippet invocation <div data-lift="MySnippet">...</div> see [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/3948df1eee6ec271). As a side noteIdea IntelliJ has native support for lift's syntax.